# Is servicerunner run in a separate thread

Tags: servicestack

In my ServiceStack webservice I am using servicerunner to write the request, response and exception log. I am having few questions regarding this. can anyone help me out?

1. Is servicerunner run in a separate thread?
2. Does an exception in the servicerunner stop the webservice from continuing to execute?

Answer (score 1):

No only 1 thread is used to handle the request, if you're using ASP.NET the ServiceStack is executed in the same HTTP Worker thread used to handle request.

An exception in Service Runner doesn't stop the entire Web Application but it would result in an error for that request.